# Swagger problem with request content-type

Tags: .net, swagger, asp.net-core-3.1

I use .net core 3.1 and have a problem with swagger.

some APIs show textbox for fill data and others show me JSON

I want to show me JSON for fill data!

Comment: Can you post code samples of the 2 types of APIs for which the Swagger documentation page shows different data inputs? Which library do you use to generate the Swagger page?

Comment: I find my answer,some apis have attribute apicontroler and they are ok,I add this attribute to all my controller